# tips to invoke a PHP function with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I really don't know how to invoke a PHP function, I have seen a lot of advice on the web, but I didn't find anything that would solve my problem.
I just want to invoke a PHP function when an `<a>` is clicked.

header.php

```
<div class="header-language">
    <form name="f1" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" />
              <?php
                foreach ($lingue as $k=>$v)
                     {
                         if ($k != $lingua)
                             {
                                 ?>
                                     <a href="" onclick="changeLang()"><img src="bandiere/<?php echo $flags[$k]; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $v; ?>" title="<?php echo $v; ?>" border="0" /></a>
                                 <?php
                             }
                     }
              ?>
   </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeLang(){
    alert("Sto per cambiare lingua");
    document.f1.action = "changelanguage.php";
    document.f1.submit();
  }
</script>
```

changelanguage.php

```
<?php

//Check if the page is called from the submit
if(isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "submit")
  {
    //Bring the current value of the cookie
    $currentlang = $_COOKIE['lang'];

    //Change the value
    if($currentlang==1) $currentlang=2;
     elseif ($currentlang==2) $currentlang=1;

    //Set the value
    setcookie("lang", $currentlang, time() + (86400 * 7), '/');
  }
```

I create the cookie by including this PHP in header.php
cookie.language.php

```
<?php

  $cookie_name = "lang";
  $cookie_value = 1;

//Check if there is already the cookie
if(!isset($_COOKIE['lang']))
  {
    //Create the language cookie
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 7), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
  }
```

Comment: Look up using ajax, however if you are changing the site language for the whole page, i would attach a get param to the href such as `href="/currentPage?lang=en"` Doesn't really make much sense to use javascript here

Comment: You also wouldn't need a form for this either, so you can remove the form and just use the `<a>` tag to pass get data

Comment: the fact is that I don't want to use get because I already use it for checking some parameters in the registration form

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use Javascript. Look into AJAX. If you want to use just PHP, set the href attribute of the link to point to the same page with an additional parameter.

```
href="/yourcurrentpage?action=change_lang"
```

This would redirect the call to your current page. Then in the current page add in checks to see if the action parameter is set and accordingly handle it.

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] == "change_lang"))
{
    //Your logic to handle change_lang
}
```

Comment: thanks, I will try, just one more thing. This code will be on all my pages, what should I put in "yourcurrentpage"?

Comment: replace it by $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. This points to the current URI that was used to load the page. for example, '/yourpage.php'. [See reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)